# Anti barking device produces ultrasonic sound that does not goes through a wooden fence. How to stop neighbor's dog from barking?

Tags: dogs

My neighbor's dog barks very often and loudly during the night time because the dog is in my neighbor's backyard 24 x 7. Therefore, we lose about 30 minutes to 1 hour of sleep every night.

There is a **wooden fence** between our house and the neighbor's.

The neighbor does not seem to truly care about stopping their dog from barking even after we talk to them nicely and politely.

I have tried to buy and use an **anti barking device** that generates ultrasonic sound automatically whenever the dog barks. But, that device does not work well because there is a wooden fence between our house and the neighbor's, and the ultrasonic sound can't go through a **wooden fence** according to this link from the manufacturer:
https://ultimatebarkcontrol.com/blogs/news/what-will-ultrasonic-sound-go-through

My questions are :

1. Is there any other **anti barking device** that generates ultrasonic sound
   that goes through a wooden fence ?
2. Can I record the sound of fireworks and play it when the dog barks
   to stop it from barking (as most dogs are scared of the sound of
   fireworks) ?
3. Is there any other different high tech devices that can stop the neighbor's dog from
   barking ?

Comment: Did you think about getting officials as the police into this? Or organisazions caring for pet's wellbeing? Maybe an area tag would help to suggest help not only for your silent nights but also for the dog to not need to suffer from the human who should care about it :(

Comment: do you know why the device are not working?is it the microphone not detecting the sound of the dog or is the speaker too weak

Comment: I just raised the device above the fence line. Since I got one that looked like a birdhouse, it didn’t look suspicious hanging in the tree.

Comment: Second the suggestion to determine if your town has noise ordinances, and if so report the noisy pooch to the police. Let them deal with telling the dog's owner that this is not acceptable and that the dog must be brought inside until it is better trained.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any other anti barking device that generates ultrasonic sound that goes through a wooden fence?

Probably not. The only way to make ultrasound of a specific frequency to **go through** something is to increase its power. You will have more problems than solution, if you try this alternative (most of the ultrasound will probably reflect back on your property).

> Can I record the sound of fireworks and play it when the dog barks to stop it from barking (as most dogs are scared of the sound of fireworks)?

It is much easier to just buy the fireworks :) The idea is that this solution is efficient ONLY if it is as loud as the real stuff - and then it is when YOU become the bad guy of the neighborhood - generating loud noises. Not to mention that those noises (without the magical lights on the sky) might actually sound like gun shots. And then... enjoy the chat with the police ;)

> Is there any other different high tech devices that can stop the neighbor's dog from barking?

Probably there is something, but also probably it is not worth it.

> I just raised the device above the fence line.

That is why I started to answer - that is the best solution to get the ultrasound to the dog. But you wrote it in the comment first :)

---

As already suggested in the comments, contact the proper authorities to deal with the situation. Deal with the neighbors to be more responsible about their dog (probably police), and "deal" with the well-being of the dog (some animal protection services). The root cause is somewhere between the neighbors and their dog - and that is what has to be fixed. The ultrasound is just a temporary workaround.

---

I am not sure if I should recommend you to watch the movie "Keeping Mum" (2005) with Rowan Atkinson (and others). In some regards, parts of the movie might be considered "dark". But overall, fun. Potentially useful for you - even though I am totally against those kinds of solutions.

Comment: It's true that ultrasound can't really go through the wooden fence and still preserves its strength, magnitude and amplitude.

Comment: what you aren't touching on are the legal consequences of doing any of the things you suggest, which can include criminal complaints as well as civil lawsuits.

Comment: @jwenting: I do not understand what you want to say. So, contacting e.g., the police about the loud noise during the night is a criminal act and will bring me a civil lawsuit?

Comment: @virolino setting off fireworks or playing loud noises definitely will get you attention from the police or civil lawsuits. And contacting the police may well get you in legal trouble as well if you do it often enough for no viable reason.

Comment: @jwenting: and which part of *"enjoy the chat with the police"* was not clear, in the context of fireworks? I also wrote *"YOU become the bad guy of the neighborhood"* - did you miss that too?

Comment: @Job_September_2020 The fact that it's not YOUR dog only complicates the situation further.