# If an anti-barking device that generates ultrasonic sound is unable to penetrate the wooden fence, what other solutions are available?

Tags: dogs, agility

The dog owned by my neighbor frequently barks loudly at night as it stays in their backyard continuously. A wooden fence separates our house from the neighbor's. Even after we tried to communicate politely, the neighbor doesn't appear to be genuinely concerned about resolving the dog barking issue. To address the problem, I attempted to acquire an anti-barking device that produces ultrasonic sound automatically when the dog barks. However, the device is ineffective due to the wooden fence that separates our houses, as the ultrasonic sound cannot penetrate it, according to the manufacturer's website.

https://dogbarkingstopper.com/products/quiet-your-neighbors-dog-with-bark-box-ultrasonic-anti-barking-device

Can an alternative anti-barking device be found that emits ultrasonic sound capable of penetrating a wooden fence?

Comment: There's no need for sound to go *through* the fence, it will much more easily go around. Can you just mount the device on top of the fence, a tree, or pole?

Comment: Very similar question: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/36837/anti-barking-device-produces-ultrasonic-sound-that-does-not-goes-through-a-woode

Comment: In what country are you? If you are in a civilized country, just call the police and report the problem. Remember to mention that you already talked with the neighbors about it. You might be breaking some law if you point a device towards the property of someone else.

Comment: @virolino indeed, you'd here be breaking all kind of laws if you pointed a device like that at your neighbour's house and caused their dog pain (which these things tend to do). Prepare for animal abuse, breach of peace, possibly even assault charges.

Comment: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/36837/anti-barking-device-produces-ultrasonic-sound-that-does-not-goes-through-a-woode?rq=1